# Spotfire :data limiting for displaying data

Tags: spotfire

I have a  requirement where I have a column Production Period of type "String" which has Year and Months data as seen below:I need to see last 6 months record in line chart. Can I limit it irrespective of any data.

Production Period 
1801 
1802
1803 
1804 
1810 
1811 
1812 
1901

I tried with following expression. String("1807") <= [Production Period] and [Production Period] <= String("1901")

But I need not specify any value as my data would keep piling.I want Production period to display last 6 months data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to convert your data to dates, and use a date difference. This can either be done as calculated columns, or expressed directly in your chart. To create date from your year-month format, the following can be used:

```
Date(
  Integer(Concatenate("20", Left(String([Production Period]),2))),
  Integer(Right(String([Production Period]),2)),
  1
)
```

This will create a Date from your current data (given that your column is named 'Production Period').

To get the last 6 months in your chart, you would formulate your limiting expression using a date difference:

```
[Date] >= DateAdd('month', -6, DateTimeNow())
```

[Date] in this expression refers to the previously calculated date value.

Comment: Using a Date column instead of strings for your x axis in line shart has the added benefit of being able to use a time hierarchy on the axis, which looks nice most of the time (i.e. axis expression like "BinByDateTime([Date],"Year.Month",1)").